# JQuery ':contains' selector - searching for text that includes nested parentheses

Tags: jquery

Assuming we have a table as follows:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span>Hello (Hi) - Bye</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>Hello (Hi (Hey)) - Bye</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The selector `$('table tbody tr:contains("Hello (Hi) - Bye")')` works properly and finds the appropriate row.

However, the selector `$('table tbody tr:contains("Hello (Hi (Hey)) - Bye")')` fails, and the error `"Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Bye'"` is generated.

The only difference is the nested parentheses in (Hi (Hey)).

I've tried using double `\` to escape the parentheses, but this didn't work for me.

Comment: It appears to work here - https://jsfiddle.net/2s9zfnof/

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? It looks like this works starting with 1.8.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses guys. It turns out that this project I'm working on still uses version 1.7.1

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed in [the jQuery 1.8 release](https://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/).

You should be able to nest multiple parentheses in any of the *newer* version of jQuery (1.8+).

This was logged as [bug #11902](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11902), which is now closed and resolved.